# Translating using variables in Symfony2 + Twig is possible?

Tags: symfony, translation, twig

The first output the string not translated:

```
{{ chart.name~'.short'|trans({}, "charts") }}
```

This one works (is the same text that `chart.name~'.short'` should output):

```
{{ 'charts.region.area.short'|trans({}, "charts") }}
```

Am i missing something? It seems it's impossible to translating dynamic text in Twig?

**EDIT**: working setting a variable (why?):

```
{% set name = chart.name ~ '.short' %}
{{ name|trans({}, "charts") }}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Symfony/Twig is trying to translate `.short` and concatenate it with contents of `chart.name`. Use parentheses to get the expected output:

```
{{ (chart.name~'.short')|trans({}, "charts") }}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. I was thinking that pipe was something like "pipe all before"...

Comment: The filters can actually be useful not just for output. For example code like this `{% if user_input|upper == 'YES' %}...{% endif %}` or `{% if rows|length == 0 %}no rows{% endif %}` can be used to avoid unnecessary data manipulation in the controller.

Comment: Yes, a lot. Even if i'm beginning Symfony2 + Twig i'm trying to learn "best practice", as your example. I'll try to put everything related to the presentation in views, avoid even to call translator (that's why my question) in controllers. In my opinion translator should be removed from controller class... it's part of the GUI!

Comment: Keeping the controller as slim as possible is the basic "good practice" in MVC design ;)

Comment: If you need to concatenate the other way round it would look like this: {{ ('contracts.states.'~object.currentState) }} Source: http://blog.webdevilopers.net/translating-dynamic-vars-concatening-object-property-in-twig-template-using-sonataadminbundle/

Answer (score 0):

when using multilanguage with symfony2 into twig you need to:

Set the Request locale, this gives the locale in which the tran twig tag will translate the word.

what I did was the following:

1- Controller part:

```
 $this->getRequest()->setLocale('es_AR');   //setting the locale to spanish in Argentina

 return $this->render('LoginLoginBundle:Default:welcome.html.twig');   //render a twig file
```

2- the twig file has a

```
<h2>{% trans %} hello {% endtrans %}</h2>
```

code with the twig tag trans,   use it this way or {{ "Text"|trans }} because {% trans hello %} do not work any more

3- in the file messeges.es.yml I got

hello: Hola

This goes in order to translate the word in the

### {% trans %} hello {% endtrans %}

,ore over you can change the hello word for any one you like and change it in the messeges.es.yml file,  example:  1: Hola  will bring Hola if the locale is set to spanish, else will bring a 1