# How to translate concatenated string in twig template using Symfony2 translator

Tags: php, symfony, twig, translation

I have a translation yml file like this:

```
tag:
  myfirsttag: Tag number one
  secondtag: Tag number two
  ....
```

and twig template like

```
    <select name="tag" required="required">
        {% for tag in tag_list %}
            <option value="{{ tag }}">{{ "tag." ~ tag | trans(domain='mydomain') }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
```

So here is the problem. Items in select are rendered like *"tag.myfirsttag"*, not translated. If I replace `"tag." ~ tag` with hardcoded string like `"tag.myfirsttag"` it works well. So obviously it is related to concatenation but official docs doesn't say anything about it.

To be more clear and simple

I can translate

```
{{ "hello.world" | trans(domain='mydomain') }}
```

but can't translate

```
{{ "hello." ~ "world" | trans(domain='mydomain') }}
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The solution is to put the string into parentheses as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7730355/1832745):

**works:**

```
{{ 'hello.world' | trans }}
```

**doesn't work:**

```
{{ 'hello.' ~ 'world' | trans }}
```

**works:**

```
{{ ('hello.' ~ 'world') | trans }}
```

Answer (score 2):

to translate contact strings you have to make this thing:

> {{ ("some string " ~ entity.type ~ " another string")|trans }}

But try writing string to translate like params:
eg:

> some.funny.string

Comment: Your answer is correct, but i had to use dynamic string because at the moment of writing I can not predict which of strings will be translated. Check first part of my question.

Answer (score 0):

Is it an associative array, right? Then you should be looping over key=>value pair

```
<select name="tag" required="required">
    {% for key,tag in tag_list %}
      <option value="{{ key }}">{{ tag | trans(domain='mydomain') }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Or is your array deeper:

```
<select name="tag" required="required">
    {% for tag in tag_list %}
      {% for key,value in tag %}
        <option value="{{ key }}">{{ value | trans(domain='mydomain') }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: No, It is not what i really looking for. I don't have any problems with keys or values of array. It is problem with using concatenated strings with `trans` filter.

Comment: I've updated my answer, see if that's the case. Looks like an XY problem here