# Symfony Translations

Tags: twig, symfony, symfony-3.1

i'm using the last version of symfony (3.1.3)
i want to trans multi vars.
but i didn't find and good solution

**right now i'm doing:**

```
{% block h1 %}{{ 'service.create'|trans }} {{ ('service'|trans) }}{% endblock %}
```

**I try :**

```
{% block h1 %}{{ 'service','service.create'|trans }} }} { %endblock %}
```

but no luck.

**I also try with**

```
{% trans %}service.create|service{% endtrans %}
```

thanks

Comment: I am not sure this works, but you can try this: `{% block h1 %}{{ ('service','service.create')|trans }} }} { %endblock %}`, Maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984545/how-to-translate-concatenated-string-in-twig-template-using-symfony2-translator or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730355/translating-using-variables-in-symfony2-twig-is-possible can help you.

Comment: not good..An opened parenthesis is not properly closed. Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "," ("punctuation" expected with value ")")

Comment: replace `,` with `~`. Also, why are the variables surrounded by quotation marks?

Answer (score 1):

You can use parameters in your translation like this:

```
{{ 'service.create'|trans }}
{{ 'service.create'|trans({'%separator%': 'any text'}) }}
```

And in your messages.ru.yml

```
...
service:
    create: ... %separator% ...
    ...
```

If your `separator` is in html, add `raw` like this :

```
{{ 'service.create'|trans({'%separator%': '<br>'})|raw }}
```

You have more details in symfony doc [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#translation-filters)

Answer (score 0):

You can translate strings in backend:

```
public function indexAction($name)
{
    $translated = $this->get('translator')->trans('Hello '.$name);

    return new Response($translated);
}
```

Or in twig templates:

```
<h1>{{ 'service.create'|trans }}</h1>
```

Each time you create a new translation resource (or install a bundle that includes a translation resource), be sure to clear your cache so that Symfony can discover the new translation resources:

```
php bin/console cache:clear
```

More info: http://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html

Answer (score 0):

I needed to just trans multi vars.
twig not support that...

Answer (score 0):

If you have a "service.yml.en" file or something like that :

```
{{ service.create|trans({}, "service") }}
```

Here the translator will search in your service.yml.en file and load the correct translation key.

If you want to do advance translations, you can use vars like that (for example) :

```
{{ (className|lower ~ "." ~ field)|trans({}, className|lower) }}
```

Here if you have a "user.yml.en" and you want to load something like "user.width", it'll work.

Good luck :)